# Font setting reset after restart in kubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, fonts

Hi I have a very annoying problem with kubuntu. Every time when I change the font, and after a restart or a root privilege is elevated the font is changed to default `ubuntu 9`. How to fix this annoying issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a fix but a workaround: [Kubuntu - cannot change fonts and widget style under sudo after upgrade to 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73818/kubuntu-cannot-change-fonts-and-widget-style-under-sudo-after-upgrade-to-11-10/)

The Kubuntu is resetting to the default Kubuntu settings (/usr/share/kubuntu-default-settings/kde4-profile/default/share/config/).

To fix this I have edited the Kubuntu defaults: /usr/share/kubuntu-default-settings/kde4-profile/default/share/config/kdeglobals.

Looking my own kdeglobals: ~/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals and copying the font information to the /usr/share/kubuntu-default-settings/kde4-profile/default/share/config/kdeglobals.

Comment: How can I edit the file as a root?

Comment: sudo, or kdesudo, or kdesu:  `kdesudo [command]`

Comment: Seems this workaround is my only option. If you found any other way please post that. BTW thanks!