# How do I change system-wide font settings in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, fonts, kde, system

How do I change the font/size for the icon captions, Dolphin text, and window decoration text?  They all went from 12 point to 10 point after I installed KDE updates on Kubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 5):

**KDE System Settings**

KDE System Settings > Application Appearance > Fonts

[image]

KDE UserBase: http://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Application_Appearance

Might also interest:

- [Font setting reset after restart in kubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141746/font-setting-reset-after-restart-in-kubuntu-12-04)
- [How to launch Configure Kde control module by command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153495/how-to-launch-configure-kde-control-module-by-command-line)